# Request a webpage with Cron

Tags: model-view-controller, unix, cron

I have an MVC architecture and since I already have an action that would be extra useful if automatically called every hour or so, I wondered if there's a way to set it up as a cron job?

Comment: Please be more specific: the framework, language, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
curl http://example.com
```

Or if the language you're using has a CLI client like PHP you could just run the script like

```
php /var/www/example.com/index.php
```

Edit:
For an MCV app it's probably easiest to use curl

Answer (score 5):

Don't know how periodic web page request is related to mvc, but you can achieve this by adding following line to crontab (1 hour period):

```
0 0/1 * * * wget <web_page_url>
```

Which is translated to: use `wget` command to request `<web_page_url>` every hour at zero minutes.